# How do i reference an existing timestream table in CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-timestream

I am using AWS CDK (Python) to manage infrastructure, including Amazon Timestream databases and tables.

Suppose i have an existing Timestream table that i want to set permissions on using CDK.

The only way i have seen to get a hold of a Timestream table is to use the `CfnTable` construct, a so called level 1 construct.  This is because Timestream does not expose level 2 constructs yet.   However,  using this construct,  i am *creating* a table as part of my stack, I am not referencing an existing resource.

For level 2 constructs,  such as `Function` for Lambda, it is possible to reference an existing resource, for example by using the `Function.from_function_name()` method. I have not found any way of doing something similar  for level 1 constructs.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the table's ARN directly as a resource in an IAM [identity-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html).  Then add the policy to the appropriate [Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/Role.html), e.g. a Lambda Role.